# How to get all directive names in a given angular app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Say I have an angular app, that has some modules and some directives.
I want to get a list of all the defined directives in this app.

For example:

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', [function(){...}]);
myModule.directive('myDirective', [function () {...}]);
myModule.directive('myOtherDirective', [function () {...}]);
var myOtherModule = angular.module('myOtherModule', [function(){...}]);
myOtherModule.directive('thirdDirective', [function () {...}]);
```

I want to write a function `getAllDirectives()` that will return `['myDirective','myOtherDirective','thirdDirective']`.

Also if possible I would also like to know which module each directive belongs to:

```
{
    'myModule': ['myDirective','myOtherDirective'],
    'myOtherModule':['thirdDirective']
}
```

How can this be done?
Please note that I need to do this from outside the app itself and after it has already loaded. I do have access to anything publicly available on the page, such as the `angular` object and the `DOM`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get all the directives defined in each module using a custom function like this one:

```
function get_directives(name) {
    var result  = [],
        invokes = angular.module(name)._invokeQueue;

    for(var i=0; i<invokes.length; ++i) {
        if(invokes[i][1] == "directive") {
            result.push(invokes[i][2][0]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

var result = {
    'myModule':      get_directives('myModule'),
    'myOtherModule': get_directives('myOtherModule'),
};
```

You could also inspect `angular.module('module_name')._invokeQueue` list for future knowledge.

Comment: That's great, Thanks!
is there also a way to find out the module names if I don't know them in advance?

Comment: I'm not sure you can get that list without some tweaks. Take a look at this question which has a nice solution for storing the modules. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24889783/angularjs-get-list-of-all-registered-modules

Comment: int i=0 does not compile

Comment: My bad, int should be var.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**
The below function will return all the directives under a module

```
function getAllDirectives(moduleName) {
    var directives = [];
    var invokes = angular.module(moduleName)._invokeQueue;
    for (var i in invokes) {
        if (invokes[i][1] === "directive") directives.push(invokes[i][2]);
    }
    return directives;
}


getAllDirectives('school') //'school' is module name
```

**Additional**

Incase if you want a ***directive definition*** of a module

```
var getDirectiveDef = function(dirName, appName){
     dirName = converToCamelCase(dirName);//converting dirname to camelCase if it has hyphen
     var allDirs = getAllDirectives(appName) //the above mentioned functoin
     _.each(allDirs, function(directive){
         if(directive[0] == dirName){
             console.log(directive);
         }
     })
}

function getAllDirectives(moduleName) {
        var directives = [];
        var invokes = angular.module(moduleName)._invokeQueue;
        for (var i in invokes) {
            if (invokes[i][1] === "directive") directives.push(invokes[i][2]);
        }
        return directives;
    }

//used to convert incase if the directive name is not in camelCase input
function converToCamelCase (string) {
    return string.replace( /-([a-z])/ig, function( all, letter ) {
        return letter.toUpperCase();
    });
}
```

example

```
getDirectiveDef('play-ground', 'school')
[or]
getDirectiveDef('playGround', 'school')
```

will print the difinition of a directive **playGround** under **school** direcitve